# JavaScript / Create object with map

Tags: javascript

I have the next definition in JS:

```
var multipartMap = {
    Parts: []
};
```

So I can do the next:

```
    multipartMap.Parts[partParams.PartNumber - 1] = {
        ETag: mdata.ETag,
        PartNumber: Number(partParams.PartNumber)
    };
```

But I want to have the ability to do the next:

```
    multipartMap[id].Parts[partParams.PartNumber - 1] = {
        ETag: mdata.ETag,
        PartNumber: Number(partParams.PartNumber)
    };
```

So `multipartMap` will be also map of objects.

**EDIT**:

to clarify, I want that in  `multipartMap[0]` would be array of Parts, and also in `multipartMap[1]` and so on.. The number will be dynamic parameter from the user.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want

```
var multipartMap = {
    SomeId: {
      Parts: []
    },
    SomeOtherId: {
      Parts: []
    }.
    etc.
};
```

Now the "id" you mention in `multipartMap[id].Parts` can be "SomeId" or "SomeOtherId".

Edited to add: you mention that the IDs will be dynamic.  That's fine and will work the same.

You'll start with

```
var multipartMap = {};
```

Then when you get an id and an array of parts, you can do

```
multipartMap[id] = {Parts: []};
```

and you'll end up with the same structure I have above.

Comment: I still can't do: `multipartMap[id].Parts[partParams.PartNumber - 1]`. Is says that `multipartMap[id]` is undefined. the id is external param i get from the user.

Comment: @OrSmith `multipartMap[id] = []` or `multipartMap[id] = {}` first.

Comment: But I don't know the ids. It dynamic, depends the user.

Comment: Edited to respond. Once you have an empty object, you can add whatever id/value pairs you want.